# 10,000+ valid email addresses for Sitecore EXM testing

Tags: exm

We have to do stress testing in Sitecore EXM, like running a campaign with 10,000 or more recipients. Any suggestion that how to arrange such big number of valid email addresses for this testing? Does EXM has any limitation in number of recipients??

Comment: Interesting that you would "stress test" the vendors service for sending the emails. Perhaps the bottleneck is more likely your email server? Would it be appropriate for you to do small batches to confirm that your campaigns run and allow Sitecore Support to handle issues if 10k emails are too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specifically answer your questions:

- **How can we have 10,000+ valid emails to test?**  For this you simply need to have a valid Gmail Email address and then by appending a plus ("+") sign and any combination of words or numbers to the end of your username (*but before the "@"*) you can create infinite variations of your Gmail address. For example, if your valid email address is `myemailaddrres@gmail.com`, then `myemailaddrres+1@gmail.com` or `myemailaddrres+2@gmail.com` will direct emails to your main address.
  https://gmail.googleblog.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html
- **Does EXM has any limitation on the number of recipients?** There is no limit on sending overall emails in EXM from the Sitecore side. It all depends on the SMTP Server configuration and limits. You can define sending limit in EXM to control the number of email messages that can be sent to **a single contact** on any given day, week, or month.
  https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/exm/91/email-experience-manager/define-sending-limits-in-the-content-editor.html

Answer (score 1):

10k contacts are not so many recipiets for EXM. 
We made tests with 50k and it works fine, it really depends on SMTP server which is used to send email.

First of all you need to generate a csv file with more than 10k users and to import into a contact list in List Manager.

The format of the csv file should be :

```
FirstName,LastName,EmailAddress
userfirstname1,userlastname1,myexmuseremail1@mailinator.com
userfirstname2,userlastname2,myexmuseremail2@mailinator.com
.....
.....
userfirstname10000,userlastname10000,myexmuseremail10000@mailinator.com
```

You need to import csv into a contacts list using **List Mananger**:

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

After you create contact list you can send email and to test.
More information you can find on Pete Navarra blog: https://sitecorehacker.com/2016/09/03/loading-xdb-contacts-with-csv-and-custom-fields/

Comment: Yep its' pretty straight forward in Sitecore to create contact list with csv. My question is about the recipients, like I can use my email address to test with 1 recipient but how can we have 10,000+ valid emails to test this. I have updated my question and explained more.

Comment: Vlad, you're welcome. Do me a favor and at least cite the blog post that you are referring to. The numbers in the pictures don't mean a whole lot by themselves.